# jetty 404 page not found with HTTP request on AWS EC2

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jetty

I have a java web application written in Jetty. I am hosting the app on AWS EC2 server listening for HTTP requests on 0.0.0.0:3000.

When I ssh to the AWS EC2 server and make an HTTP request, 
e.g. curl "http://localhost:3000/users/get", I got the following error

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 404 </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 404</h2>
Problem accessing /users/get. Reason:
<pre> Not Found</pre>

<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>
</body>
</html>
```

I think the request is rejected by jetty...
But when I deploy the app on my Mac and make the same request on my mac. It worked...

Do I have to make any additional configuration change to AWS EC2 server?

Thank you.

Here is my security group:
Type    Protocol    Port Range  Source
HTTP    TCP          80         0.0.0.0/0
All TCP TCP          0 - 65535  0.0.0.0/0

And the instance is not in the private subnet..

Here is the output after I ran

```
sudo nmap -T Aggressive -A -v 127.0.0.1 -p 1-65000


    Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-07-08 21:16 UTC
NSE: Loaded 110 scripts for scanning.
NSE: Script Pre-scanning.
Initiating SYN Stealth Scan at 21:16
Scanning localhost (127.0.0.1) [65000 ports]
Discovered open port 80/tcp on 127.0.0.1
Discovered open port 25/tcp on 127.0.0.1
Discovered open port 111/tcp on 127.0.0.1
Discovered open port 8080/tcp on 127.0.0.1
Discovered open port 22/tcp on 127.0.0.1
Discovered open port 38940/tcp on 127.0.0.1
Discovered open port 5006/tcp on 127.0.0.1
Completed SYN Stealth Scan at 21:16, 0.44s elapsed (65000 total ports)
Initiating Service scan at 21:16
Scanning 7 services on localhost (127.0.0.1)
Completed Service scan at 21:16, 6.08s elapsed (7 services on 1 host)
Initiating OS detection (try #1) against localhost (127.0.0.1)
Retrying OS detection (try #2) against localhost (127.0.0.1)
Retrying OS detection (try #3) against localhost (127.0.0.1)
Retrying OS detection (try #4) against localhost (127.0.0.1)
Retrying OS detection (try #5) against localhost (127.0.0.1)
NSE: Script scanning 127.0.0.1.
Initiating NSE at 21:16
Completed NSE at 21:16, 5.04s elapsed
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000025s latency).
Not shown: 64993 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE VERSION
22/tcp    open  ssh     OpenSSH 6.6.1 (protocol 2.0)
| ssh-hostkey: 2048 4f:a3:44:91:06:8d:a3:25:03:d7:8f:37:8f:de:f0:2d (RSA)
|_256 d7:5f:46:f1:67:25:ee:9e:fa:d7:7a:dd:60:b7:e2:0b (ECDSA)
25/tcp    open  smtp    Sendmail 8.14.4/8.14.4
| smtp-commands: ip-172-31-34-184.us-west-2.compute.internal Hello localhost [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you, ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES, PIPELINING, 8BITMIME, SIZE, DSN, ETRN, DELIVERBY, HELP,
|_ 2.0.0 This is sendmail 2.0.0 Topics: 2.0.0 HELO EHLO MAIL RCPT DATA 2.0.0 RSET NOOP QUIT HELP VRFY 2.0.0 EXPN VERB ETRN DSN AUTH 2.0.0 STARTTLS 2.0.0 For more info use "HELP <topic>". 2.0.0 To report bugs in the implementation see 2.0.0 http://www.sendmail.org/email-addresses.html 2.0.0 For local information send email to Postmaster at your site. 2.0.0 End of HELP info
80/tcp    open  http    Apache httpd 2.4.18 ((Amazon) PHP/5.6.22)
|_http-favicon: Unknown favicon MD5: CF2445DCB53A031C02F9B57E2199BC03
|_http-generator: Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)
|_http-methods: No Allow or Public header in OPTIONS response (status code 200)
| http-robots.txt: 36 disallowed entries (15 shown)
| /includes/ /misc/ /modules/ /profiles/ /scripts/
| /themes/ /CHANGELOG.txt /cron.php /INSTALL.mysql.txt
| /INSTALL.pgsql.txt /INSTALL.sqlite.txt /install.php /INSTALL.txt
|_/LICENSE.txt /MAINTAINERS.txt
|_http-title: Welcome to ec2-52-10-97-122.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com | ...
111/tcp   open  rpcbind 2-4 (RPC #100000)
| rpcinfo:
|   program version   port/proto  service
|   100000  2,3,4        111/tcp  rpcbind
|   100000  2,3,4        111/udp  rpcbind
|   100024  1          38940/tcp  status
|_  100024  1          43083/udp  status
5006/tcp  open  jdwp    Java Debug Wire Protocol (Reference Implementation) version 1.8 1.8.0_60
8080/tcp  open  http    Jetty 9.2.3.v20140905
|_http-methods: No Allow or Public header in OPTIONS response (status code 404)
|_http-title: Error 404
38940/tcp open  status  1 (RPC #100024)
No exact OS matches for host (If you know what OS is running on it, see http://nmap.org/submit/ ).
TCP/IP fingerprint:
OS:SCAN(V=6.40%E=4%D=7/8%OT=22%CT=1%CU=33690%PV=N%DS=0%DC=L%G=Y%TM=5780183E
OS:%P=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)SEQ(SP=102%GCD=1%ISR=10E%TI=Z%CI=I%II=I%TS=8)
OS:OPS(O1=MFFD7ST11NW7%O2=MFFD7ST11NW7%O3=MFFD7NNT11NW7%O4=MFFD7ST11NW7%O5=
OS:MFFD7ST11NW7%O6=MFFD7ST11)WIN(W1=AAAA%W2=AAAA%W3=AAAA%W4=AAAA%W5=AAAA%W6
OS:=AAAA)ECN(R=Y%DF=Y%T=FF%W=AAAA%O=MFFD7NNSNW7%CC=Y%Q=)T1(R=Y%DF=Y%T=FF%S=
OS:O%A=S+%F=AS%RD=0%Q=)T2(R=N)T3(R=N)T4(R=Y%DF=Y%T=FF%W=0%S=A%A=Z%F=R%O=%RD
OS:=0%Q=)T5(R=Y%DF=Y%T=FF%W=0%S=Z%A=S+%F=AR%O=%RD=0%Q=)T6(R=Y%DF=Y%T=FF%W=0
OS:%S=A%A=Z%F=R%O=%RD=0%Q=)T7(R=Y%DF=Y%T=FF%W=0%S=Z%A=S+%F=AR%O=%RD=0%Q=)U1
OS:(R=Y%DF=N%T=FF%IPL=164%UN=0%RIPL=G%RID=G%RIPCK=G%RUCK=G%RUD=G)IE(R=Y%DFI
OS:=N%T=FF%CD=S)

Uptime guess: 0.108 days (since Fri Jul  8 18:40:45 2016)
Network Distance: 0 hops
TCP Sequence Prediction: Difficulty=258 (Good luck!)
IP ID Sequence Generation: All zeros
Service Info: Host: ip-172-31-34-184.us-west-2.compute.internal; OS: Unix

NSE: Script Post-scanning.
Initiating NSE at 21:16
Completed NSE at 21:16, 0.00s elapsed
Read data files from: /usr/bin/../share/nmap
OS and Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 23.46 seconds
           Raw packets sent: 65110 (2.869MB) | Rcvd: 130217 (5.475MB)
```

Comment: Can you paste your security group? And also is your instance in a Private subnet?

Comment: @error2007s I have updated the information!

Comment: Run this command from your MAC terminal "telnet <ec2 Public IP address> 3000" and let me know the put put.

Comment: @error2007s Trying 52.10.97.122...
telnet: connect to address 52.10.97.122: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

Comment: @error2007s I ssh to the aws ec2 instance that runs the app and send the curl command. And the output is 404 page not found.

Comment: Run this command on the EC2 "sudo nmap -T Aggressive -A -v 127.0.0.1 -p 1-65000" and then try the Curl

Comment: @error2007s still page not found...

Comment: so does it have something to do with the ec2 instance setting?

Comment: Some how your port 3000 is blocking the HTTP request. Because you see telnet command failed for port 3000. Try one last thing "curl "http://localhost/users/get"

Comment: @error2007s I have updated the output produced by the nmap command

Comment: @error2007s I think jetty server somehow blocks my http requests

Comment: One min I guess this is the solution instead of localhost use "127.0.0.1" in curl command.